# users and logins in sql server 2005 express

Tags: sql, permissions, authentication

I created a login named mylogin with password= 'pass_1'

Then i logged into sql server using this login & tried to create a database , which gave the error that permission denied.

Then i executed this : sp_addsrvrolemember 'mylogin',  'dbcreator'

Then, again I logged into sql server using above login & tried to create a database, this time the database was created successfully

This was because I added the dbcreator server role for the login.

But, then i created a USER myloginuser for LOGIN mylogin ,
then executed this query: 
execute as user = 'myloginuser'

then again i tried to create a database, but it failed. why so?

when the login MYLOGIN to which the user MYLOGINUSER is associated has the permission to create a database then why does the user does not have the permission? then whats the solution for this? do i have to grant permission to the user separately irrespective of the permissions granted to the login?

also, a user which is created for a login , have to be created inside a database? is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default user for the LOGIN [mylogin] was mylogin (which was created executing

> sp_addsrvrolemember 'mylogin',
>   'dbcreator'

Hence this mylogin user had the db create permission. But you have created a MYLOGINUSER for the same Login. So the existing user mylogin was set to orphaned user, hence the mylogin Login dropped the db creator permission.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but then how do i give create table permission to myloginuser then? when i am giving it using sp_addsrvrolemember then it says --login does not exist. so do i have to use GRANT?

Comment: @sqlchild, Run the below script                                    use YOUR_DB
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner',myloginuser

Comment: sir, i want to know that in sp_addsrvrolemember , a username cannot be given? we have to give a login name to it? because when i created a user separately and then tried to grant dbcreator server to role to him then it gave error. means that if we want that the user is created with the same name as of the login then we can use sp_addsrvrolemember, because it created the user itself, but when we separately create a user & then want to grant permission to him, then we cannot use it.

Comment: sir, can you tell me a book or link where i could find full detail of schema, users, roles, logins. because am confused with all these. am messed up with them.

Answer (score 1):

Is the SQL Server  Authenticationmode set to Mixed instead of Windows?
Ypu'll have to set it to mixed.

A user must be created at the SQL Server level and given permissions in (mapped to) a database.

Comment: dear sir, if i have chosen Windows mode, then would i not be able to give permissions to a new login?